# Spark driver disassociated and removed by the master

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a cluster made by two slaves and one master and set up and I submit a jar (scala) to the spark master (192.168.1.64):

```
spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 --class tests.elements target/scala-2.10/zzz-project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

After quite sometime running just fine it stops abruptly with the last lines on the terminal being

```
...
15/08/19 17:45:24 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 411292.0 with 6 tasks
15/08/19 17:45:24 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Stage 411292 contains a task of very large size (2762 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB.
15/08/19 17:45:24 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 411292.0 (TID 1832, 192.168.1.64, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2828792 bytes)
15/08/19 17:45:24 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 411292.0 (TID 1833, 192.168.1.62, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2310009 bytes)
15/08/19 17:45:24 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 411292.0 (TID 1834, 192.168.1.64, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2669188 bytes)
15/08/19 17:45:24 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 411292.0 (TID 1835, 192.168.1.62, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2295676 bytes)
15/08/19 17:45:24 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 411292.0 (TID 1836, 192.168.1.64, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2847786 bytes)
15/08/19 17:45:24 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 411292.0 (TID 1837, 192.168.1.64, PROCESS_LOCAL, 2913528 bytes)
Killed
```

and the error occurring at the master log is the following:

```
...
15/08/19 16:09:49 INFO master.Master: Launching executor app-20150819160949-0001/0 on worker worker-20150819160925-192.168.1.64-51640
15/08/19 16:09:49 INFO master.Master: Launching executor app-20150819160949-0001/1 on worker worker-20150819160938-192.168.1.62-38007
15/08/19 16:15:44 INFO master.Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.64:46823 got disassociated, removing it.
15/08/19 16:15:44 INFO master.Master: Removing app app-20150819160949-0001
15/08/19 16:15:44 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.64:46823] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
15/08/19 16:15:44 WARN master.Master: Application testPageRank is still in progress, it may be terminated abnormally.
...
```

Both workers have in their logs something like this

```
...
15/08/19 16:15:49 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20150819160949-0001/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
15/08/19 16:15:50 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@192.168.1.64:54799] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

and

```
...
15/08/19 16:15:43 INFO worker.Worker: Executor app-20150819160949-0001/1 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
15/08/19 16:15:43 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@192.168.1.62:53325] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

respectively. The work/app files contain something like this

```
...
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 387758.0 (TID 1803). 1911 bytes result sent to driver
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 4.0 in stage 387758.0 (TID 1806). 1911 bytes result sent to driver
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block rdd_1206_5 locally
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 5.0 in stage 387758.0 (TID 1807). 1911 bytes result sent to driver
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block rdd_1206_3 locally
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 3.0 in stage 387758.0 (TID 1805). 1911 bytes result sent to driver
15/08/19 16:15:44 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver 192.168.1.64:46823 disassociated! Shutting down.
15/08/19 16:15:44 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.64:46823] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
15/08/19 16:15:45 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
15/08/19 16:15:46 INFO util.Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

and

```
...
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO storage.BlockManager: Found block rdd_1206_0 locally
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 2.0 in stage 387758.0 (TID 1804). 1911 bytes result sent to driver
15/08/19 16:15:41 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 387758.0 (TID 1802). 1911 bytes result sent to driver
15/08/19 16:15:42 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver 192.168.1.64:46823 disassociated! Shutting down.
15/08/19 16:15:42 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
15/08/19 16:15:42 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.64:46823] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
15/08/19 16:15:42 INFO util.Utils: Shutdown hook called
```

respectively. There seem to be no other error in hdfs or spark.

I am suspecting that the error lies in the master log, the third line (`15/08/19 16:15:44 INFO master.Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.64:46823 got disassociated, removing it.`) but I can't figure out why. I tried changing the `spark.akka.heartbeat.interval` to 100 as suggested in some posts but no luck. Anyone would know why it happens and how to solve this? Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't think this is the same issue.

Comment: I have your same problem. Find a Solution?

Comment: Not really. At some point I moved to other things. But I suspect it might have to do with the fact that my cluster was too small in terms of RAM (2-3 machines with 4-6G of RAM each). Therefore, I am still interested in an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a very similar question here [WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155563/warn-reliabledeliverysupervisor-association-with-remote-system-has-failed-addr)

The problem is likely to be the lack of memory. Adding more memory (or in that case more nodes) should solve the problem.

(Alternately, needing less memory should work too of course).