# WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr

I am running the following sentence on aws spark

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

case class Wiki(project: String, title: String, count: Int, byte_size: String)

val data = sc.textFile("s3n://+++/").map(_.split(" ")).filter(_.size ==4 ).map(p => Wiki(p(0), p(1), p(2).trim.toInt, p(3)))

val df = data.toDF()
df.printSchema()

val en_agg_df = df.filter("project = 'en'").select("title","count").groupBy("title").sum().collect()
```

can after about 2 hours running get the following error:

```
WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system    [akka.tcp://sparkYarnAM@172.31.14.190:42514] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
15/10/15 17:38:36 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 172.31.14.190:42514
15/10/15 17:38:36 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster has disassociated: 172.31.14.190:42514
15/10/15 17:38:36 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:43340] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
15/10/15 17:38:36 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal: remote Rpc client disassociated
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks for 1 from TaskSet 0.0
15/10/15 17:38:36 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4736.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4736, ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 lost)
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 1 (epoch 0)
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove   executor 1 from BlockManagerMaster.
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(1, ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal, 58890)
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 1 successfully in removeExecutor
15/10/15 17:38:36 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal: remote Rpc client disassociated
15/10/15 17:38:36 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:60961] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason: [Disassociated] 
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks for 2 from TaskSet 0.0
15/10/15 17:38:36 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4735.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4735, ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 lost)
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 2 (epoch 0)
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 2 from BlockManagerMaster.
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(2, ip-172-31-14-190.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal, 58811)
15/10/15 17:38:36 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 2 successfully in removeExecutor
```

what does that mean ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: The executor likely ran out memory.  So you need to inspect the container log for one of the executors that was lost and possibly the yarn nodemanager log on the node it ran on.

Comment: @ChristopherB thx a lot for the comment!

Comment: Did it work out or find more error information?

Comment: @ChristopherB I think you are right. It seems to be a out-of-memory on executor, because it went well if I add more machine to the cluster

Answer (score 0):

The answer already appears to be provided in the comments:

> It seems to be a out-of-memory on executor, because it went well if I
>   add more machine to the cluster